# Scrollbar with tktext - RScript Tkinter

Tags: scrollbar, tk-toolkit, rscript

I'm trying to run a scrollbar in an R script, but I can't connect events. Based on the python examples, everything seems to be ok.

```R
require(tcltk) || stop("tcltk support is absent")
require(stats)

have_ttk <- as.character(tcl("info", "tclversion")) >= "8.5"

done <- tclVar(0)

if(have_ttk) {
  tkbutton <- ttkbutton
  tkcheckbutton <- ttkcheckbutton
  tkentry <- ttkentry
  tkframe <- ttkframe
  tklabel <- ttklabel
  tkradiobutton <- ttkradiobutton  
}

dialog.t.test <- function(){
  tt <- tktoplevel()
  tkwm.geometry(tt, "400x450")
  tkwm.resizable(tt,1,1)
  
  tkgrid.columnconfigure(tt, 0, weight=1)
  tkgrid.rowconfigure(tt, 0, weight=1)
  
  SV<<-tkscrollbar(tt, orient='vertical')
  textbox1 <<- tktext(tt, width=30, height=10, font=('Helvetica 16'), wrap = "none")#, yscrollcommand=tkset(SV))
  
  tkgrid(textbox1, row=0, column=0, sticky="ewns")
  tkgrid(SV, row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
 
  tkconfigure(SV, command=tkyview(textbox1))
}

#with(airquality, dialog.t.test())
dialog.t.test()

for (index in 1:100){
  tkinsert(textbox1,"end",index - 1 ,sep = "\n")
  tksee(textbox1,"end")
}
```

I don't know how to improve the syntax:

```
yscrollcommand=tkset(SV)
```

and

```
tkconfigure(SV, command=tkyview(textbox1))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct syntax:

```R
require(tcltk) || stop("tcltk support is absent")
require(stats)

have_ttk <- as.character(tcl("info", "tclversion")) >= "8.5"

done <- tclVar(0)

if(have_ttk) {
  tkbutton <- ttkbutton
  tkcheckbutton <- ttkcheckbutton
  tkentry <- ttkentry
  tkframe <- ttkframe
  tklabel <- ttklabel
  tkradiobutton <- ttkradiobutton
  tkscrollbar <- ttkscrollbar  
}

x<- tclVar()

dialog.test <- function(){
  tt <- tktoplevel()
  tkwm.geometry(tt, "400x450")
  tkwm.resizable(tt,1,1)
    
  tkgrid.columnconfigure(tt, 0, weight=1)
  tkgrid.rowconfigure(tt, 0, weight=1)
  
  sv<<-tkscrollbar(tt, orient='vertical',command=function(...)tkyview(textbox1,...))
  textbox1 <<- tktext(tt, width=30, height=10, font=('Helvetica 16'), wrap = "none",yscrollcommand=function(...)tkset(sv,...))
  
  tkgrid(textbox1, row=0, column=0, sticky="ewns")
  tkgrid(sv, row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
}

dialog.test()

for (index in 1:100){
  tkinsert(textbox1,"end",index - 1 ,sep = "\n")
  tksee(textbox1,"end")
}
```